# Converting a string to float for a pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python, pandas, integer, series

I am trying to convert the following pandas.core.series.Series to a float.
Code:

```
from yahoo_fin.options import get_calls
ticker = 'aapl'
ticker_calls = get_calls(ticker)
df = ticker_calls['Implied Volatility']
con = pd.Series(df).astype('float')
```

also tried:

```
df.astype('float')
```

output:

```
could not convert string to float: '733.59%'
```

when just printing the series/df the data appears:

```
 1. 733.59%
 2. 657.03%
 3. 633.79%
```

however I can't perform any statistics/math on this. The end goal is to be able to do:

```
(df['Risk_free'] + df['IV'])
```

with the output being: an `int` or `float`.

example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
['Risk_free']0.15 + ['IV']7.3359 = ['new col']7.35089
```

output I am getting now:

```
 4. 1.500%733.59%
 5. 1.500%657.03%
```

Comment: Have a look at this blog, https://pbpython.com/currency-cleanup.html

Comment: have tried: pd.to_numeric(con) and get Unable to parse string "4,685.16" and Unable to parse string "4,685.16" at position 134

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can strip off the '%' sign..

```
from yahoo_fin.options import get_calls
ticker = 'aapl'
ticker_calls = get_calls(ticker)
df = ticker_calls['Implied Volatility']
con = df.str.rstrip('%').astype(float)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.Series(['12%', '12.5%', '35%', '50%', '88.880%'])
df.str.rstrip('%').astype(float)
0    12.00
1    12.50
2    35.00
3    50.00
4    88.88
dtype: float64
```

Comment: In stripping the '%' sign I get: "could not convert string to float: '4,685.16'"

Comment: float can not have two decimal points, you should use masking to find such scenario and remove everything from second decimal points.

Comment: It is a comma and decimal. So once the comma is dropped it should read 4685.16

Comment: ya, do that then